# JQuery - Pass data to callback, from each element in a collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my HTML I have these links:

```
<a class="more-comments-link" id="more-comments-1135" href="#">Show More Comments</a>
<a class="more-comments-link" id="more-comments-4357" href="#">Show More Comments</a>
```

and so on.

Every link has same class and a unique ID.

In JQuery I do this:

```
var $el = $( "a.more-comments-link" );
```

Here I get  a collection of all links.
I want to add `click` event to each element and get the ID from each element in a collection and pass it to callback.

I have tried this:

```
$el.click({id: $el.attr('id')}, tst);
```

tst is just a simple callback function with event parameter.
All this do is just gets the ID from first element in a collection.

Comment: `tst` is the callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
$el.click(tst);
```

Inside `tst`, `this` will be the target element, and you can use `this.id` to get its ID.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$el.click(tst);

function tst(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
  
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

Comment: Same thing Barmar answered earlier. That is it, thanks to all of you guys.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function myFunction (id){
}

$("body").on('click', 'a.more-comments-link', function (){
     var myId =  $(this).attr('id');
     myFunction(myId);
})
```

Comment: in callback itself I will later further pass the same callback again so I need it to have a name and not to be anonymous function